# Creating HapiJs server that can serve complex web pages

Tags: node.js, rest, hapi.js

I have just started learning Node.js and hapi.js. What I am trying to accomplish now is build a REST web server that should also have a web interface for configuration and statistics collection.

I found that [Inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) plugin allows serving static pages and, as I understand, this limits me to loading a single web page that consists of a single file.

However, what I do not understand is whether it is possible to setup hapi.js to serve a full dynamic webpage with `css`, `js` and other files referenced within its body.

Am I heading the wrong direction with this or else how can I setup my scenario?

Comment: Have a look at Vision for dynamic rendering of HTML from templates. CSS and JS you can serve using Inert though because they're normally just static files.

Answer (score 1):

You can serve multiple static files from a specified directory.

Just tried out `inert` with `hapi`, using this example:

https://github.com/hapijs/inert#static-file-server

Inert has no problem serving multiple static files from a given directory, e.g `public`.

So you'll have no issue serving multiple static html, css, js files from a specified dir. You can then build a dynamic JSON api using Hapi, and have that consumed by your js client-side code, served from static js files in your public dir.

If you are needing templating, where you generate dynamic content on the serverside, hapi can do that out of the box, check out:

http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views

Sorry if this isn't what you mean, do feel free to clarify if not :-)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The [vision](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) plugin is used for templating, which is what I think you're after. If you want to bundle css and js files along with your pages, you can put them in a public directory and serve that with the [inert plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/inert). And then you only need to reference the relative path in whatever html file you're trying to render.

Here's a simple example that uses [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Inert is responsible for serving your css and js files while vision still renders your templates.

`./index.js`

```
var hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new hapi.Server();
server.connection({port: 5555});

server.register([require('vision'), require('inert')], (err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err; 
    }

    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: require('handlebars')
        },
        relativeTo: __dirname + '/',
        path: 'www'
    });

    var homeroute = {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: (request, reply) => {
            reply.view('index', {name: 'cuthbert'});
        }
    };

    var publicassetsroute = {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/public/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: './public',
                listing: false,
                index: false
            }
        }
    };

    server.route(homeroute);
    server.route(publicassetsroute);

    server.start((err) => {
        console.log('server started -- ' + server.info.uri)
    });

});
```

`www/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hapi Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Hapi Happy Test.</h1>
    <p>This is a test page. Woo!</p>
    <p>My name is {{name}}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`public/index.css`

```
p {
    color: blue;
}
```